# Changing the color of a point on an object

Tags: colors, webgl

I am pretty new to the shaders in WEBGL,I have an object(.Json) in my webgl scene. When I click on the object with my mouse, I want the clicked point to change its color to blue. I can get the click locations on the object in x,y,z format( called mouseclicks), and I am aware I need to use the shaders, this is what I have so far in the  shaders.

```
varying vec3 mouseclick;
attribute mouse;


//vertex shader
void main()
 {
  vec4 mouse =(mouseclick,1.0);

 }

  //fragmant shader

 void main()
 {

  colorout = vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

  gl_FragColor =vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided shader will not work - the usage of varyings and uniforms is incorrect. Also, it is quite difficult to do it in the shader itself. You can follow below steps:

- Use a mechanism to find out object that is clicked (this is tricky, you need to be familiar with model to world space, transformations)
- For this object, set the color to change as required (in the application code). Send this as an attribute for this object
- Shader can be a generic shader, that sets the color as a varying, and the frag shader can use this to interpolate the colors